# Deal with change in size of inserted elements in the array

Tags: java

I have the following code in which I initialized the array to a certain number and then in a queue of for loops, the data is inserted. But the data insertion is dynamic. Sometimes the size is 42, Sometimes it is 49 and sometimes it is 46 or may be lesser or greater depends on the elements it is fetching to insert.

```
if(val.equals("Recommended for you")) {
            js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)");
            num=42;
        }
        else if(val.equals("Trending deals")) {
            js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1500)");
            num=50;
        }
String[] arr = new String[num];

        for(int i=0;i<=6;i++) {
            arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
            //System.out.println();


        }
        //      
        s.get(0).click();

        for(int i=7;i<=13;i++) {
            arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
            //System.out.println();


        }
        s.get(0).click();
        try {
            for(int i=14;i<=20;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=21;i<=27;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=28;i<=34;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=35;i<=41;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();

            for(int i=42;i<=48;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //  System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=49;i<=55;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=56;i<=62;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=63;i<=69;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=70;i<=76;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
            s.get(0).click();
            for(int i=77;i<=83;i++) {
                arr[i]=allelements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
                //System.out.println();


            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        Arrays.toString(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<=num-1;i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            //System.out.println();
        }
```

I need to go and change the num value each time to run my code without exception. Else Array out of bounds exception and Null pointer exceptions are thrown when I try to print array values at last as shown in code after sorting array elements. I tried just to declare the array to try solving the issue. But syntactically that didn't work and compiler warned me.

Can anyone help me to handle this so that for any size, code can run without any error and my code becomes generic ? One thing is I don't want any user input to be given(Scanner class) and the code should work on the elements inserted in for loops and hence according to that length of the array.

Comment: If you want something that acts a little like an array, but can change in size, just use a `List`, such as an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an Array, use a `List<String>`. So the code would be:
`List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>()` instead of `String[] arr = new String[num];`. To add elements to it, use `arrList.add(...)` instead of `arr[i] = ...`.